# Android list style SMS mysql query

Tags: android, mysql

I'm unable to resolve the mysql query to bring the users on top. Its getting failed by trying allot of queries in different ways. Issue is we don't know if sender sent latest msg or receiver.we have conversion table having sender and receiver ids in it. Now we have to show those on top who sent latest messages themselves or whom our sender xyz sent latest message. We can't group by sender or receiver cuz if we do then we may lost allot of those records to whom our sender sent message. Plz if u can help me resolving this issue to show the list of those on top who sent latest messages themselves or whom our sender xyz sent latest message, exactly like we see in the list of Android SMS app

Comment: please show us how the schema looked like.

Comment: The schema looks like this. Table name conversation.. Columns id, senderid, receiverid, message, sentdate

Comment: and you want to get the latest `senderid, receiverid` based on `sentdate`?

Comment: also note that as like in smartphones, I need to display a list of senders/receivers as a thread, ordering as descending on basis of sentdate.no matter if sender has sent message to A, or A has sent message to B, the thread of A and B will be on top if any of them has sent latest message. Same goes with the other threads if A sent message to C Or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    conversation a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  senderid, receiverid, MAX(sentDate) maxDate
            FROM    conversation
            GROUP BY senderid, receiverid
        ) b ON  a.senderid = b.senderid AND
                a.receiverid = b.receiverid AND
                a.sentDate  = b.maxDate
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Please note, I need to display a list of Senders/Receivers.In smartphones,your name dont display anywhere,but only the other person's name displays,and when u open the thread,it shows all conversation b.w you and him,and this list relies on latest sent date,whether u sent him a msg or he sent u a msg.I need to show this list of Names only,not the conversation,but the list of users should be displayed relying on the sender or receiver's message sent time means latest thread on top,then next and so on..

Comment: I tried modifying your given query as: 
SELECT a.* FROM conversation a
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT IF(sender_id=1,receiver_id,sender_id), MAX(sent_date) maxDate
 FROM conversation
 GROUP BY sender_id
) b ON  a.sender_id = b.sender_id AND a.receiver_id = b.receiver_id 
AND a.sent_date  = b.maxDate
This gave me great results,but one thing is making problem here.If only A has sent message to B, or B has sent message to A,this conversation is not showing in it. Can you pleas resolve.
Thanks

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: This worked perfect:
SELECT b.snd,maxDate FROM conversation a
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT IF(sender_id=1,receiver_id,sender_id) as snd,receiver_id,sender_id, MAX(sent_date) maxDate
 FROM conversation
 GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id
) b ON  a.sender_id = b.sender_id AND a.receiver_id = b.receiver_id 
AND a.sent_date  = b.maxDate 
ORDER BY maxDate DESC

Though it gave the results multiple times, but GROUP BY was disturbing the records, so I handled the code thru PHP after getting these results.

Thanks again.